# i dont see the big difference between Responsive and adaptive

Tags: css, responsive-design, adaptive-design

Here is the demo URL for [Adaptive / responsive](http://liquidapsive.com/)

First time entering into adaptive theme, i just read this [Article](http://www.responsys.com/blogs/nsm/cross-channel-marketing/difference-responsive-adaptive-web-design/) and looked the demo site.

when i change my browser size and i dont see the big difference on the responsive and adaptive. can you suggest, is there any way, which shows the differentiation of the responsive and adaptive

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that an adaptive layout has set layouts for certain screen sizes, which means that the content is set to fixed sizes in each of those layouts, and it just toggles between them.

A fully responsive layout means that everything is scaled using percentages and relative units of measurement, so that it constantly responds to ANY screen size, not just a certain set of sizes.

If you open the responsive demo on that page, you will notice that the width's of things constantly scale with your browser, while the adaptive one does not.

Comment: So basically, responsive : liquid :: adaptive : fixed-width?

Comment: Responsive and liquid are essentially the same, with the difference there being that responsive also uses the adaptive layouts at different breakpoints, whereas liquid only scales. And fixed-width/static is essentially the same as adaptive except that it only has 1 layout and 1 breakpoint, while an adaptive layout can have multiple. Responsive and static are basically at the ends of the spectrum, with liquid and adaptive sitting somewhere in between.

Comment: Another way to say this, or think about is, is that an adapative layout is a set of multiple static layouts, a static layout at multiple different breakpoints.  The fact that there are multiple static layouts at multiple breakpoints is what makes it "adaptive".